# How to write regex expression for this type of text?

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to extract the price from the following HTML.

```
<td>$75.00/<span class='small font-weight-bold text-
danger'>Piece</span></small> *some more text here* </td>
```

What is the regex expression to get the number 75.00?

Is it something like:

```
<td>$*/<span class='small font-weight-bold text-danger'>
```

Comment: Most often, it is .*, but regexes vary over languages. Then you often have to mark with parens what you like to capture, so it would be "<td>(.*)/<span ..."

Comment: Obligatory, [You Shouldn't Be Using Regex To Parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1547004).  Use an actual DOM parser like `beautifulsoup` or `requests-html`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is a special character in regex, so you need to escape it with a backslash. Also, you only want to capture digits, so you should use character classes.

```
<td>\$(\d+[.]\d\d)<span
```

As the other respondent mentioned, regex changes a bit with each implementing language, so you may have to make some adjustments, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with `/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/`.

- `[0-9]` matches a single number. In this example you should get the number `7`.
- The `+` afterwards just says that it should look for more then just one number. So `[0-9]+` will match with `75`. It stops there because the character after `5` is a period.
- Said so we will add a period to the regex and make sure it's escaped. A period usually means "every character". By escaping it will just look for a period. So we have `/[0-9]+\./` so far.
- Next we just to add `[0-9]+` so it will find the other number(s) too.

It's important that you don't give it the global-flag like this `/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g`. Unless you want it to find more then just the first number/period-combination.

---

There is another regex you can use. It uses the parentheses to group the part you're looking for like this: `/<td>\$(.+)<span/`
It will match everything from `<td>$` up to `<span`. From there you can filter out the group/part you're looking for. See the examples below.

```
// JavaScript

const text  = "<td>$something<span class='small font-weight..."
const regex = /<td>\$(.+)<span/g
const match = regex.exec(text) // this will return an Array

console.log( match[1] ) // prints out "something"
```

---

```
// python

text = "<td>$something<span class='small font-weight..."
regex = re.compile(r"<td>\$(.+)<span")

print( regex.search(text).group(1) ) // prints out "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Wrap your `<td>` inside a table, use for example [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get your element and get the first node from the childNodes.

That would give you `$75.00/`.

To remove the `$` and the trailing forward slash you could use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or use a regex like [`\$(\d+\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/hBK2Ag/1) and get the value from capture group 1.

```js
let html = `<table><tr><td>$75.00/<span class='small font-weight-bold text-
danger'>Piece</span></small> *some more text here* </td></tr></table>`;
let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
let result = doc.querySelector("td");
let textContent = result.childNodes.item(0).nodeValue;
console.log(textContent.slice(1, -1));
console.log(textContent.match(/\$(\d+\.\d+)/)[1]);
```